# NSTimer causing error (glitching) - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have a timer that runs every 60 seconds, but for some reason after the first 2 times it runs, it starts running in random short intervals until the program crashes. Within 4 minutes it runs 7 times then crashes.

```
- (void) resetDatabase {
    count++;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        ConDAO *con = [[ConDAO alloc] init];
        DatabaseManager *manager = [DatabaseManager sharedManager];
        NSError * error;
        //        NSURL * storeURL = [[[manager managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator] URLForPersistentStore:[[[[manager managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] lastObject]];
        //        [[manager managedObjectContext] reset];//to drop pending changes
        //        if ([[[manager managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator] removePersistentStore:[[[[manager managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] lastObject] error:&error])
        //        {
        //            // remove the file containing the data
        //            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:&error];
        //            //recreate the store like in the  appDelegate method
        //            [[[manager managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator] addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error];//recreates the persistent store
        //        }



        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Caf_student_cards"];
        NSArray *arr = [[manager managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        if(error != nil){
            [self showError];
            return;
        }
        for (NSManagedObject *data in arr){
            [[manager managedObjectContext] deleteObject:data];
        }


        NSLog(@"*****************************");
        NSLog(@"updating");
        NSLog(@"count: %d", count);
        NSLog(@"*****************************");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self populateDatabase:0 con:con];

            double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

                [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(resetDatabase) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            });
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: You're scheduling another timer every time the method runs without cancelling the old one so you have multiple timers going after the first one fires for the first time.  Either make the timer non-repeating or schedule it outside of the method.

Comment: The start time of that timer is going to be fairly random, too, since it depends on a background queue getting somewhere, even though the timer is created on the main queue.

Comment: I set it to non-repeating and it worked.